# read_sql превращает большие целые числа в числа с плавающей точкой - как этого избежать?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Всем привет.

Я беру данные из БД с помощью функции Pandas `read_sql()`.
В ней хранятся id, представляющие собой целое число из 20 знаков и которые могут быть null.
Особенность функции read_sql состоит в том, что если данные в поле содержат null, то тип данных поля переводится из int во float. В результате число переводится в экспоненциальный формат, но самое главное - теряется точность (а это неприемлемо):

```
    Код:
    print(int(float(10000000000000000000 + 1)))

    Результат:
    10000000000000000000
```

Я пытался использовать аргумент coerce_float = False, но это не работает.
Как можно с этим справиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. речь идёт об `id` (идентификаторе) и вам врядли понадобится совершать арифметические действия с данным столбцом, то удобнее всего читать данный столбец как строку:

```
qry = """SELECT cast(id as varchar), ... FROM table_name WHERE ..."""
df = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я имел про запас это решение на крайний случай, просто тогда это усложняет запрос - вместо простого select * from tbl нужно явно перечислять все поля, либо все поля с id таким образом... select tbl.id1, tbl.id2, tbl.* from tbl. Хочется добиться более высокого уровня абстракции и зашить это в скрипт питона:-)

Comment: @mlader, с такими большими числами (20 знаков) по-другому у вас, скорее всего, не получится. Т.к. в Python вы уже получите неточное число. Можете создать `view` на стороне DB и пользоваться им...

Comment: @mlader, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)